# Remove All Gnome Panels

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I'm using xmonad with xmobar, but I still use Gnome for some system services.  I would like to remove all of the Gnome panels since I don't use them.  I can remove all but the last panel. The "Delete This Panel" is gray out on the last one.

I've tried "killall gnome-panel" but it just pops back up. I've also tried auto-hiding and setting it to transparent. That's pretty close but still a little annoying to have something there which sometimes blocks clicks for the bottom part of the screen.

Is there any way to kill gnome-panel or remove the panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/gnome-panel ~/.panel_backup
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked, but the second did not.  I removed the panel key but it still comes up.  Can you update or remove that part of the answer?

Comment: Hmm, not certain why the second didn't work.